# How to retrieve filled TextField from persistence

Tags: ios, swift

I have an error when loading secondViewController with a textField and an action button so the user can fill it with some number and get it saved to UserDefaults

The idea is to be able to come back to secondVC and that the TextField shows there with the same value that input originally by the User

[image]

```
class MainViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var A3TextField: UITextField!

    @IBAction func calc(_ sender: Any) {
        let A3 = Cell(name: "A3", sheet: "", value: Double(A3TextField.text!)!)
        print(A3)

        Cell.saveCellsUserDefaults(cells: [A3], forKey: "main")
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }
}

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var B3TextField: UITextField!

    @IBAction func calc2(_ sender: Any) {
        let B3 = Cell(name: "B3", sheet: "", value: Double(B3TextField.text!)!)
        print(B3)

        // persist
        Cell.saveCellsUserDefaults(cells: [B3], forKey: "second")
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // retrieve from persists and draw in TextField

        let cellB3FromUD = Cell.getCellsUserDefaults(forKey: "second")
        print("---> cellB3FromUD \(cellB3FromUD[0].value)")
        B3TextField.text = "\(cellB3FromUD[0].value)"
    }
}

struct Cell: Codable {

    var name: String = ""
    var sheet: String = ""
    var value: Double = 0

    init(name: String, sheet: String, value: Double) {
        self.name = name
        self.sheet = sheet
        self.value = value
    }

    static func saveCellsUserDefaults(cells: [Cell], forKey: String)  {
        let encoder = JSONEncoder()
        if let encoded = try? encoder.encode(cells) {
            let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
            defaults.set(encoded, forKey: forKey)
        }
    }

    static func getCellsUserDefaults(forKey: String)-> [Cell] {
        var cells = [Cell]()
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        if let cellData = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: forKey) {
            if let cellX = try? decoder.decode([Cell].self, from: cellData) {
                cells = cellX
                return cellX
            }
        }
        return cells
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi I saw the code, maybe I don't understand the question, but if you change the line in SecondViewController from this let cellB3FromUD = Cell.getCellsUserDefaults(forKey: "second") to let cellB3FromUD = Cell.getCellsUserDefaults(forKey: "main") then it will pass the data from first one to the second is this what you want to achive??

Comment: the issue is I don´t want to show what is in "main", I really want to show whatever was filled in cellB3 in secondVC, thus in "second"

Comment: currently on viewDidLoad of SecondViewController it is trying to laod something which is not exist. Add some empty value first.

Comment: If I add some empty value first, then it will show that empty value,which I don´t want. I want the original value that was filled in the textfield by the user in secondVC the first time he pressed on calc in the SecondVC

Comment: Yes but currently your code is crash because on first run you are using this (cellB3FromUD[0].value) and UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "second") is empty

Comment: Can you explain what the bug is? Is it that you want the cells in vc1 and vc2 to be always the same but they are not? If that’s the problem, which one is wrong?

Comment: this should be in you viewDidLoad of SecondViewController let cellB3FromUD = Cell.getCellsUserDefaults(forKey: "second")
        if cellB3FromUD.count > 0 {
            print("---> cellB3FromUD \(cellB3FromUD[0].value)")
            B3TextField.text = "\(cellB3FromUD[0].value)"
        }

Comment: Or is it that you want them to be different but they are the same? What? What is the “error” here? Please give step by step instructions saying what to do, what you expect, and what you get.

Comment: I think m1sh0 solved it, though you need to wrap your last string around  "\" "( )", yes it is a good solution for the viewDidLoad to put an if ( ) statement before so that the error does not come when loading the viewDidLoad of the secondVC the first time, thanks